# SP.ArrayListEnumerator check if length = 0

Tags: javascript, csom

I have one object in my code that is of type `SP.ArrayListEnumerator`, and I want to check if its length is 0 or not.

How do I do that using JavaScript?

Comment: Where did you get the object from? often you get an `ArrayListEnumerator` from an object that inherits `SP.ClientObjectCollection`, where you have count.

Comment: Hi Anders, when you get an item from sharepoint list, you get enumerator of the type SP.ArrayListEnumerator

Comment: Sounds to me that you have called `.getEnumerator()` on an object, if so, there is probably a `.get_count()` on that same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SP.ArrayListEnumerator` don't have a `count` or `length` property. Your only option is to iterate and get the count as below

```
var count = 0;
while(SP.ArrayListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    count++;
}
//SP.ArrayListEnumerator.reset() - Resetting so you can use it again from the beginning

alert(count);
```

Comment: Additionally, since Brittany only cares whether the count is zero or not, she can break out of the loop as soon as the first item is enumerated. `var isZero = true; while(listEnumerator.moveNext()){isZero = false; break;}` That way it doesn't have to iterate any more than necessary.